# Explaining a certain result with Matrix Method of Simplex Method

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, simplex

I have been learning Linear Programming, and at the moment, the Simplex Method. I have been looking at [this resource](http://staff.aub.edu.lb/~bm05/ENMG500/Set_3_revised_simplex.pdf).

I understand all the steps up until the last statement (*page 5*), where we find the max $x_1$ and $x_2$. I understand why $Z = 90$ and $x_2 = 30$ but it bewilders me why $x_1 = 0$ instead of $20$.

Any ideas or pointers are super helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: $x_1$ is not basic

Comment: @MarcelloSammarra is that because it is not in $x_B$?

Comment: yes, the basic variables are $S_2$ and $x_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I too am learning the Simplex algorithm.

According to Page 4, Step 4, the new basis set is $\{S_1, x_2\}$.  If you understand the derivation of ${\bf{}X}_b$ on Page 5, Step 2, you can see that $S_1 = 20$ and $x_2 = 30$.

Let's back up:  The basis set ${\bf{}X}_b$ on Page 4 began as $\{S_1, S_2\}$.  Steps 3 and 2, respectively, determined that $S_2$ would be leaving the basis set, while $x_2$ would be entering.  That brought us to ${\bf{}X}_b$ = $\{S_1, x_2\}$.

If a variable does not appear in the basis set, its value is $0$ (*necessarily, I think*).  Since $x_1$ is not in the basis set, its value must be $0$.

To verify that $x_1 = 0$, consider from the augmented form $x_1 + x_2 + S_1 = 50$ at the top of Page 4 that $x_1 = 50 - x_2 - S_1$, so $x_1 = 50 - 30 - 20 = 0$.